# gcloud init: removing old users from selection list

Tags: configuration, gcloud

I did some training with qwicklabs.
Each time I ran commands from my local computer using terminal.
First was `gcloud init`.
In the first steps there are suggestions to use defined accounts or add new.
After completing some of the labs there are a lot of old users, which I would like to remove.
Is it possible to remove them?
I use windows but can not find configuration/cache file.

[image].

Comment: The CLI credentials are stored here on Windows: **C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\gcloud** I wrote an article that explains the details: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-where-are-my-credentials-stored/

Comment: That actually gave me an idea. There is a credentials.db file which stores the logins. I renamed it and new initial file was recreated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove an account from the auth list, you should use the [`gcloud auth revoke`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/revoke) command.

For example:

```
gcloud auth revoke student-00-d4029f1bd014@qwiklabs.net
```

To verify this is working, instead of typing `gcloud init`, you can use [`gcloud auth list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list) to list all the accounts whose credentials have been obtained using `gcloud init`, `gcloud auth login` and `gcloud auth activate-service-account`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--all` flag with `gcloud auth revoke` as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/revoke).